# azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova 0.8.0 error: expected '>'

Tags: visual-studio, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, adal

I'm getting the following error when building my project:

```
In file included from Project Name/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ms-adal/ADAL.framework/Headers/ADAL.h:63:
  Project Name/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ms-adal/ADAL.framework/Headers/ADKeychainTokenCache.h:73:38: error: expected '>'
  - (nullable NSArray<ADTokenCacheItem *> *)allItems:(ADAuthenticationError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error;
                                       ^
  Project Name/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ms-adal/ADAL.framework/Headers/ADKeychainTokenCache.h:73:39: error: expected ')'
  - (nullable NSArray<ADTokenCacheItem *> *)allItems:(ADAuthenticationError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error;
                                        ^
  Project Name/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ms-adal/ADAL.framework/Headers/ADKeychainTokenCache.h:73:3: note: to match this '('
  - (nullable NSArray<ADTokenCacheItem *> *)allItems:(ADAuthenticationError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error;
    ^
  2 errors generated.
```

This plugin worked previously when using 0.6.0 & 0.7.1 but I cannot get 0.8.0 to work.
Currently using Cordova 5.4.0 and Node 4.5.0, where I am Building to iOS, iPad Air running iOS 8.3, building from Windows 10 through a Macbook Air remotely. Building with Visual Studio 2015 update 1.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something quite simple. I was running an Xcode version lower than 8, which seemed to cause the errors above. Upgrading to Xcode 8.0 fixed the issue.